# How to print the document from document library in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, development

I need to print the item(document) from document library using single click. So I need the print button in ribbon or provide the printing option in ECB.

Need help to do this either server side code or client side in SharePoint 2013.

Thanks in advance for your help.